# How to access those server-side controls from the Angular App?

Tags: asp.net, angular, webforms

I know that Angular 4 isn't ideal as a client-side application that sits on a server-side application, especially on legacy ASP.net web forms applications. If I had my way, I would rework the entire system so that I can create a resource and an authentication server, and the Angular SPA would make API calls to those two servers. But I can't do that per requirement.

I know how to build the Angular app and set it up so that it runs on the .aspx page. However, I am required to access ASP.net controls to write values to from inside the Angular app, and I need to access a button to programmatically click to fire the server side click event. How would I do these two tasks?

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of the parts that you get working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I always create backing code that does the actions for the UI elements - as long as you don't need server-side code to change UI, you can turn that backing code into an API...and the rest of your work turns into AJAX calls.

Comment: I'll post that minimal code later. I'll have to filter out a lot of code for brevity and confidentiality.

Comment: @theGleep - I'm not sure what you mean, but the click of that submit button needs to read content from the other elements that the Angular app would've written to, and post back to show some sort of confirmation message. Web API calls are so tempting but I was specifically told not to duplicate code.